# AWS Api Gateway Lambda Integration is not working with api key

Tags: cors, cross-browser, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

My API gateway with Lambda Integration works fine. However when I make an api key required it does not work. "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://some-aws-api-gateway. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)."

A few findings:
Api gateway without api key `X-Api-Key` works for both POSTMAN and Browser. Api Gateway with api key only works for POSTMAN.

I have checked the headers multiple times, and they all are what they should be.

```
{
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":"true",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"GET,OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token",
    "Content-Type":"application/json"
}
```

I decided to do an experiment. What I did was to remove api key requirement and changing `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"` to `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"https://example.com/")`. Now request from the browser had this error: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match 'https://example.com' which is the intended result. This simply means to me that the headers I have set up in AWS Api Gateway are correct.

What I know so far:

1. `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"` with no api key required **WORKS**
2. `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"` with api key **DOES NOT WORK**, ERROR: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://some-aws-api-gateway. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)."
3. `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"https://example.com"` (or any domain different from origin) with api key required **DOES NOT WORK**, ERROR: same as 2
4. `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"https://example.com"` with no api key **DOES NOT WORK**, ERROR: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match 'https://example.com'

If you notice, once the api key is required (2 & 3) you will get the same error message.

My question is why CORS fail when api key (`X-Api-Key`) is required, but pass when the api key is not required? This leads me to believe that the CORS headers on the Api Gateway is fine, however, the authentication process of validating the api key from browser request is where the problem lies. Why is the CORS header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` missing on Api key required? I am wondering if the api key/headers needs to be encoded to a certain format or something.

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("X-Api-Key", apiKey);   

var requestOptions = {
   method: 'GET',
   headers: myHeaders,
   redirect: 'follow',
   mode: 'cors',
   credentials: 'include'
};

fetch("https://some-aws-api-gateway", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => console.dir(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem has been resolved. The root of the problem was that I required an api key for the `OPTIONS` method in the AWS Api Gateway console. However all other methods that does actual CRUD operations eg. `GET`and `POST` must have "API Key Required" set to `true`.

So set "API Key Required" to `false` in method request panel for OPTIONS method. For more information you can check out this aws forum thread [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=658072#658072).